# Reindexing : When do you use 'Update on schedule' or 'update on save'?

Tags: magento2, indexing

In Magento 2, there are 2 methods of indexing:

- Update on schedule
- Update on save

I understand the differences between these two modes, but what I'm wondering (and what [the documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html) is not telling something about) is in what kind of situation you would choose one over the other?

So in what scenario would it be better to use 'index on schedule' and vice versa?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update on Save** :The index is set to update whenever a change is saved.

**Update on Schedule** :The index is set to update on schedule according to a cron job.

- On a small store,**Update on Save**  is fine and will add very little
  load.
- If you have a larger store with  multiple admins, working in the
  backend then your indexes could be getting triggered constantly. 
  **Update on Save** ties up MySQL and for large stores can take hours to complete. To avoid this, it is recommended setting your
  indexers to **Update on Schedule**.  Then only run the indexers as
  needed (via command)  or via a scheduled cron task.

Comment: Hi @MoeHannadi when i enabled "Update on schedule" whether we need to set up any crons at server level except default 3 crons?

Comment: Hi Nagaraju. You just need the 3 default cron jobs. But make sure you set up them correctly. you can use this link for cron setup:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Based on magemojo server, we setup magento crons syntaxes mentioned here https://prnt.sc/njx843 & magento admin end enabled reindex mode for stock is https://prnt.sc/njwwe0 Update on Schedule, so automatically product stock statuses will reindex for every minute am i correct? please clarify

Comment: If Update by Schedule is in use, is it required to also manually reindex for example once a day? One extension development company suggested that, but shouldn't the indexes be updated automatically when Update by Schedule is set?

Comment: Not sure if its the same for M2 but Sonassi recommends only having "Price" and "Stock" set to update-on-save. All others should be update-on-schedule. However, this is for M1. I would assume the same should be for M2.

Answer (score 4):

**Update on save** (realtime): Indexed data is updated as soon as a change is made in the Admin. (For example, the category products index is reindex after products are added to a category in the Admin.) This is the default.

**Update by schedule (schedule)**: Data is indexed according to the schedule set by your Magento cron job.

**Update by schedule (schedule):** Using a cron job (preferred because indexing runs every minute)

**`Update on save :`** Using the magento **indexer:reindex [indexer]** command, which reindexes selected indexers, or all indexers, one time only

Comment: This I understand. But my main question is: **in what situation** would you choose for save or schedule?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I have a catalog of 1.4 lac. , I am using magento enterprise ,all index are setup manual update and having reindexing issue , products updates are not showing on frontend until i reindex using SSH,  If I use script to reindex, there is no effect on frontend , what is the best solution to get the updates immediately  on frond end ? what is the other best way to peform reindex except using SSH ?

Comment: Hi @MoeHannadi when i enabled "Update on schedule" whether we need to set up any crons at server level except default 3 crons?

Comment: when your magento is used by many operators that frequently update product and category, use Update By Schedule for Category Products and Product Categories to avoid mysql deadlock and this can cause another indexer to fail for example elasticsearch. Make sure that magento minutely cron is running.

Comment: @SureshChikani, if I set **Update by schedule**, do I still need to add `5 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex` in `crontab -e` ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its the same for M2 but Sonassi recommends only having "Price" and "Stock" set to update-on-save. All others should be update-on-schedule. However, this is for M1. I would assume the same should be for M2.

> ### Production stores
>
> Only "Product Prices" and "Stock Status" should be set to "Update on
> save", all others must be manual. A cron should be configured to
> re-run indexes at an appropriate non-production hour.

https://www.sonassi.com/help/magento-management/index-management

Comment: Because of the improvements made to Indexing for M2, the risk of deadlocking DB and impacts to frontend customer experience have been significantly reduced. I operate an installation of 5 stores with a catalog containing around 20K SKUs and in M1, indexing was problematic. We've not had any trouble so far with M2 indexing since launching our M2 store in November 2020.